Pro-$p$ Group with solvable subgroup of finite Index is solvable?
Let $p$ be a prime, and let $G$ be a pro-$p$-group. Suppose that $G$ contains a solvable subgroup $H$ of finite index. Is it true that $G$ is also solvable? Since any finite $p$-group is nilpotent (and hence solvable), we may assume that $G$ is infinite, and $H$ is not normal.

If I understand your question correctly, we can reason as follows.

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $G$ be a pro-$p$ group.  If $G$ contains a
solvable subgroup of finite index, then $G$ is solvable.

Proof.
Let $H$ be a solvable subgroup of finite index in $G$.
Then the closure $\bar{H}$ is also solvable and has finite index in $G$.
Since $G$ is a pro-$p$ group, there exists an open normal subgroup $A$ of $G$
contained in $\bar{H}$ such that $G/A$ is a $p$-group.
We have that $A$ is solvable (as a subgroup of a solvable group),
$G/A$ is a finite $p$-group and hence nilpotent, and therefore it is solvable.
It follows that $G$ is solvable.
